# How mock $_FILES in slim framework

Tags: php, unit-testing, file, mocking, slim

I tried a lot to mock $_FILES in slim framework test case.

$_FILES

Comment: Just mock it then. `$_FILES = ['foo']; print_r($_FILES);` results in `Array
(
    [0] => foo
)`. Define the array as necessary. Update your post with what you tried a lot.

Comment: @james it won't work if we define static array. Test expecting real file $_FILES

Comment: In Slim you should change the request object per test and not the $_FILES super-global.